# Не отображается изображение в редактировании изображения WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не отображается картинка в консоли, когда я пытаюсь ее редактировать встроенными средствами для установки миниатюр. Самое интересное что на локальном сервере все работает. На картинке внизу вы можете увидеть как это выглядит.

Уже полностью перезаливал сайт и пересоздавал базу, не знаю какой файл за это отвечает, так что в код админки пока не лез..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может на хостинге нету модуля пхп для работы с изображениями php-gd ?

Comment: а разве бывают модули, которые нельзя вшить кодом? В плане я не понимаю зачем вообще нужен модуль к PHP, а второе: как это проверить или установить..

Comment: залить на хостинг скрипт с `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` и посмотреть есть ли там в активных модулях/расширениях php-gd. Если нет - нужно гораздо больше информации о том где у вас этот хостинг и что он из себя представляет, чтоб дать ответ. Навскидку "apt-get install php-gd"

Comment: Вы правы, такого модуля я не нашел, но если его нельзя закачать на сервер я вряд ли смогу его подключить. У меня бесплатных хостинг, я проверяю его для будущего, возможного, сотрудничества. Я так понимаю мне идти к ним в поддержку...

Comment: У хероку есть gd вроде. Но да, спросите у поддержки, может там есть какой-то способ активировать модуль. Расширение-то популярное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая проблема, на хостинге версия php 5.4 стояла, поставил версию php 5.5 заработало.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.26

Comment: Сейчас стоит PHP Version 5.5.26?

Comment: Да, у меня стоит эта версия PHP

Comment: Картинки то случайно не на русской раскладке называются. Попробуйте назвать картинку именно англ. буквами (например, "footbal") и проделайте процедуру заново.

Comment: В названии картинки были пробелы, но не русские буквы. Назвав картинку английскими буквами слитно изменений не наблюдается.

Comment: Какая версия вордпресс стоит?

Comment: Не думаю что проблема в этом. Товарищ Dmitry V. подсказал что проблема может крыться в отсутствии php-gd и похоже он прав.

Comment: А ты случайно сайт не делал на компе, а потом заливал на хостинг. Например через Denwer делал, а теперь в интернет заливаешь.

Comment: Именно так я и делаю.

Comment: Для начала, Залейте повторно сайт, но перед этим базу MYSQL откройте в notepad++ и замените название старого сайта на новый, всего около 15 замен. Что бы все url которые вначале называются локалкой стали вначале новым доменом вашим

Comment: Далее. в файле .htaccess делаем следующие изменения:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Где ‘blog/’ – путь после доменного имени
И так же. Устанавливаем атрибуты 777 для папки wp-content/uploads и всех подпапок.

Comment: 15-ти? Откуда столько, я нашел только 2 и оба в options...
Не понял только что за атрибуты 777 для папки загрузок.

Comment: Ну у вас может и меньше будет. А атрибуты это, заходите на FTP и на все папки правой кнопкой мыши \ права доступа к файлу \ отмечаете все галочки

Comment: Сделано, ноль реакции.

Comment: Отсутствии php-gd. Пробовали или тоже не помогло?

Comment: Уже спросил у администрации, показали что есть. Я сейчас попробую полностью поставить сайт с нуля, без плагинов и тем. Это значительно сузит пространство для поисков. Отпишу о результате.

Comment: Ок, я облажался тотально, без темы и плагинов с чистым вордпресс все работает, пойду поставлю тему и проверю результат, затем подобавляю плагины и проверю в них ли проблема.

Comment: В общем очевидно я напартачил, сервер пал пока я это делал, так что я завершу проверять в одиночку, да и если проблема где-то и появиться вновь то это уже совсем другая история... Благодарю за помощь и терпение!

Comment: Бывает ) Удачи )

Answer (score 1):

Обычно тут две причины. Или картинки в принципе нет, или так как у тебя картинка большая и у тебя стоят ограничения на обработку файлов таких размеров. Попробуй уменьшить вес и перезалить.

Comment: А как сменить ограничение? Точнее на локалке ж работает, вы имеете ограничения php.ini?

Comment: max_input_time = число
Максимально возможное время в секундах, которое скрипт может потратить на обработку загружаемых данных.

memory_limit = 8M
Максимальный объем памяти, выделяемый сценарию, составляет, например, 8 Мбайт.

Comment: Но для начала открой картинку в браузере по пути. Она могла просто не залиться.

Comment: картинка точно присутствует на сервере, я ее выбираю из списка картинок в разделе "мультимедия". Проблема в том что файл php.ini мне не доступен на изменение из-за бесплатного бесплатного хостинга, но так установлены такие значения: max_input_time 30
memory_limit 128M

Comment: Сожалею, http://www.host-food.ru/. Переезжай. 300р в год.

Comment: Да хороший хостинг, просто я его решил опробовать перед покупкой, а тут такие штуки что особо-то и нечего пробовать :)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте установлен ли на сервере модуль php-gd. В соответствии с [этим](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/what-are-php-extensions-and-libraries-wp-needs-and-or-uses) ответом, он необходим.

Comment: Благодарю. Пошел спрашивать у поддержки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но ответ кроется не в этой библиотеке. Я не тщательно просмотрел информацию файла php.ini, но поддержка показала мне это: 
GD Support enabled
GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Comment: @Levelleor, включите [все ошибки](http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php) и посмотрите error.log

Comment: У меня нет доступа к файлу php.ini, но заменив строку define('WP_DEBUG', false); на define('WP_DEBUG', true); я получил не маленький списочек ошибок... Правда все ошибки по идее одинаковые из темы и выглядят вот так: "Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/u263743197/public_html/wp-content/themes/orange_flash/functions/theme_options.php on line 812", и несколько ошибок не из темы, но принадлежат футеру и сайдбару. Пожалуй исправлю эти 2 сейчас.

Comment: ну это все не то, надо искать связанное с image-edit, думаю. В общем это гадание на кофейной гуще :) но наверняка проблема с конфигурацией сервера.

Comment: Да, это все не то ибо я не заметил что это всего-лишь Notice... Даже не Warning

Comment: ну error мог быть в момент сохранения, а не в момент показа, потому я рекомендую смотреть именно лог.